# cat map re-transformation  

Tags: chaos, ds.dynamical-systems, arithmetic-dynamics

Hi,

Is there any way of moving from one cat map transformation to the other without resetting parameters?
For example, suppose you  have two matrices '$A$'and '$B$' each permuted with different cat map parameters namely '$p_1$','$q_1$' and '$p_2$','$q_2$'. The goal is by having the permuted matrix of  '$A$' under '$p_1$', '$q_1$' which we call '$A_p$' and parameters of '$B$' in this case '$p_2$' and '$q_2$', we get a matrix called '$A_bp$' which is equal to permuting the original '$A$' with '$p_2$' and '$q_2$'? obviously, we are not allowed to re-permute '$A_p$' to get '$A$' and apply '$p_2$', and '$q_2$' on '$A$'.

Thx

Comment: Can you clarify what your definitions are?  By "cat map" I assume you mean "toral automorphism", that is a map $\mathbb{R}^d/\mathbb{Z}^d$ given by a matrix $A\in SL(d,\mathbb{Z})$, and probably you want $A$ to have no eigenvalues on the unit circle.  But I don't know what you mean by "cat map parameters" or "permuted matrix", so right now I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Vaughn: Thanks for your comments and sorry for the confusion. Yes I meant "toral automorphism" with the application of something like Arnold Cat Map where we have a map $  \begin{bmatrix}
x_n\\y_n
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
1&p\\ q&1+pq
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_{n-1}\\y_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix} mod~ n$. Since $det\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
      1 & p\\
       q & pq+1

     \end{bmatrix}
       \end{pmatrix}=1 $ then the map is area preserving. So we permute $A$ and $B$ using the map with two different parameter $p_1$,$q_1$ and $p_2$ and "q_2" which gives us $A_p$ and $ B_p$.

Comment: Then, we want to use $B_p$ and $p_2$, $q_2$ ,$p_1$, and $q_1$ to permute $B_p$ further such that the result is like permuting $B$ with $p_1$ and $q_1$ using the above mapping.

Comment: Still don't understand the question: what do you mean by "moving from one transformation to another"?

Comment: @Quas: I mean instead of permuting $B_p$ back to $B$ with its parameters and then permuting the resulted $B$ with $A$'s parameter to get the same permuted matrix as $A_p$, directly go from $B_p$ to $A_p$ without doing back and forth.

Comment: Here is the simple explanation. Is the map defined above have  associative property? Is it possible to do Map(Map($A_{p,q}$)$_{p1,q2}$)=Map($B_{p2,q2}$? If it is possible, how $p_1$ and $q_1$ can be calculated based on only $p,q,p_2$, and $q_2$ ?